# Using regex with SQL Server and REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: regexp-replace

So, I am using REGEXP_REPLACE with SQL. I am trying to get a count of the number of signs (which are identified by the IDs bellow. The tricky part is that an instance could contain commas, semi-colons, colons, N/A, or any combination of those. I provided some examples below.

| id | sign_number |
| --- | --- |
| 103854 | N/A |
| 103584 | 9008 |
| 134851 | 5324, 5629, 6220, 6222, 8323, N/A |
| 125843 | 72017, 72X06, N/A |
| 158434 | 62033; 62034; 62843; 62844, 9471; 9472, 6805;, N/A |
| 485764 | 40001; 40007 |

Each one is a row in the table and the id is a unique value.

I was trying to use regexp_replace to remove those things and then replace them with whitespace so I can count the number of whitespaces.

This is what I was trying to use and I am not sure why it isn't working. When I test the regex on this site, https://regex101.com/, it highlights all the right things. But when I run it in SQL (via Toad for Oracle) it doesn't do it correctly. I am sure I am doing something wrong with leading or trailing whitespaces.

```
regexp_replace(sign_number,'[;,:]|(?:N\/A)|\s', ' ') as regex_result, 
regexp_count(sign_number,'\s') as counts
```

It gives me this:

| id | sign_number | regex_result | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 103854 | N/A | N/A | 0 |
| 103584 | 9008 | 9008 | 1 |
| 134851 | 5324, 5629, 6220, 6222, 8323, N/A | 5324 5629 6220 6222 8323 N/A | 5 |
| 125843 | 72017, 72X06, N/A | 72017 72X06 N/A | 2 |
| 158434 | 62033; 62034; 62843; 62844, 9471; 9472, 6805;, N/A | 62033 62034 62843 62844 9471 9472 6805 N/A | 7 |
| 485764 | 40001; 40007 | 40001 40007 | 1 |

so, the end goal for counts would be:

| id | sign_number | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 103854 | N/A | 0 |
| 103584 | 9008 | 1 |
| 134851 | 5324, 5629, 6220, 6222, 8323, N/A | 5 |
| 125843 | 72017, 72X06, N/A | 2 |
| 158434 | 62033; 62034; 62843; 62844, 9471; 9472, 6805;, N/A | 7 |
| 485764 | 40001; 40007 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I based my solution on your original post of all "sign" values being supplied in one long string.  Now I see from the edit that they will come from separate strings.  I'm not clear how the original data will come so I'm just going to leave this as I think my solution still has value.  You can just tweak it to meet your needs or use parts of it. I suppose I'll find out quick enough if that is not true as folks here are not shy!  lol

Oracle's flavor of regex does not support lookaheads.  Instead you need to "loop" through the string using the "connect by" construct, which creates a "level" variable for you to use that is set to each iteration.

Here, the with statement just sets up test data, here used like a temp table (A great way to supply data when asking for help).  The query loops through the string then using connect by, parsing into substrings the sets of characters followed by 'N/A', a decimal-space or the end of the string for the number of times this pattern is found.  For each substring, it then returns the level, then the optional substring of the set of characters that is followed by 'N/A', or a decimal, then a space or the end of the line.

Then the count is calculated, by counting the number of substrings found in the current level that are followed by one or more of ,a space;: and subtracting from that the count of 'N/A' string if that is found.  The 'prior' lines handle the cases of mutiple lines so counts don't get messed up.

Try it a few times with various inputs in the with clause and see how it goes. Use union all's to add more lines to the tbl table.

```
with tbl(bridge_number) as (
  select 'N/A 9008 5324, 5629, 6220, 6222, 8323, N/A 72017, 72X06, N/A 62033; 62034; 62843; 62844, 9471; 9472, 6805;, N/A 40001; 40007' from dual
)
select level, 
regexp_substr(bridge_number,'((.*?)(N\/A|\d))( |$)', 1, level, null, 1) as regex_result, 
regexp_count(regexp_substr(bridge_number,'((.*?)(N\/A|\d))( |$)', 1, level, null, 1), '(.*?)([, ;:]+)')+1 - 
regexp_count(regexp_substr(bridge_number,'((.*?)(N\/A|\d))( |$)', 1, level, null, 1), '(N\/A)') as count
from tbl
connect by level < regexp_count(bridge_number, '(N\/A|\d |$)') + 1
and prior bridge_number = bridge_number
and prior sys_guid() is not null;


LEVEL REGEX_RESULT                                          COUNT
----- ----------------------------------------------------- -----
    1 N/A                                                       0
    2 9008                                                      1
    3 5324, 5629, 6220, 6222, 8323, N/A                         5
    4 72017, 72X06, N/A                                         2
    5 62033; 62034; 62843; 62844, 9471; 9472, 6805;, N/A        7
    6 40001; 40007                                              2

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: So, I edited my post to make more sense. This is my first post to Stack Overflow and I am still learning the formatting! I did however use a single portion of your suggested code and it seems to have worked perfectly! I just removed the part about the levels! regexp_count(regexp_substr(bridge_number,'((.*?)(N\/A|\d))( |$)', 1), '(.*?)([, ;:]+)')+1 - 
regexp_count(regexp_substr(bridge_number,'((.*?)(N\/A|\d))( |$)',, 1), '(N\/A)') as count @Gary_W

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had a dilemma as I deleted my original answer since, after your edits, it really no longer applied.  However, the technique of using connect by to parse through the list if it was supplied as one long string is worth sharing so I figured I'd just leave it for posterity and create a new answer.  As it stands now, it is much easier anyway!

All you have to do is the counts.  See my other post for the explanation.

```
with tbl(id, sign_number) as (
  select 103854, 'N/A' from dual union all
  select 103584, '9008' from dual union all
  select 134851, '5324, 5629, 6220, 6222, 8323, N/A' from dual union all
  select 125843, '72017, 72X06, N/A' from dual union all
  select 158434, '62033; 62034; 62843; 62844, 9471; 9472, 6805;, N/A' from dual union all
  select 485764, '40001; 40007' from dual
)
select id, sign_number,
regexp_count(sign_number, '(.*?)([, ;:]+)') + 1 - 
regexp_count(sign_number, '(N\/A)') as count
from tbl;


        ID SIGN_NUMBER                                       COUNT
---------- ------------------------------------------------- -----
    103854 N/A                                                   0
    103584 9008                                                  1
    134851 5324, 5629, 6220, 6222, 8323, N/A                     5
    125843 72017, 72X06, N/A                                     2
    158434 62033; 62034; 62843; 62844, 9471; 9472, 6805;, N/A    7
    485764 40001; 40007                                          2

6 rows selected.
```